# How to install libmemcache on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-managers, libmemcached

I need to install **libmemcache** onto a CentOS box.  I don't have root privileges, so preferably everything would go somewhere inside my home directory.

I've tried downloading **libmemcached-1.0.12.tar.gz** and building it with `./configure --prefix=/home/charrison`, `make install`, but this inscrutably failed.  Something clued me to install **libevent**, which helped somewhat, but ultimately the **libmemcached** make is now failing as follows:

```
In file included from ./libmemcached/common.h:72,
             from ./libmemcached/csl/common.h:40,
             from libmemcached/csl/context.cc:38:
./libmemcached-1.0/memcached.h:46:27: error: tr1/cinttypes: No such file or directory
```

And, even if I resolved that, who knows how many more prerequisites exist?

Then it occurred to me "Hey, isn't this what 'package managers' are for?  To know about and install prerequisites?"  I discovered that **RPM** is the CentOS package manager, but I drowned in the man page.  I'm not even sure whether it is capable of downloading packages or knowing about dependencies.

The only "package manager" I have any experience with is **cpan**, which is pretty powerful and simple.

So I'd really like to know

- how to install **libmemcached** in CentOS privately, and if possible,
- what a package manager does and does *not* do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer to the two questions. Hope it helps you.

1. how to install libmemcached in CentOS privately, and if possible,

   (Step 1) download libmemcached RPM package from CentOS mirror site such as `ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/<centos version>/os/<your arch>/Packages/`.

   (Step 2) extract the package in a current directory by using rpm2cpio command.

   `e.g., $ mkdir foo; cd foo; rpm2cpio ../libmemcached-*.rpm | cpio -di`
2. what a package manager does and does not do

   `rpm` command allows you to find out what packages are installed(*1).
   Also, you can confirm the dependencies among multiple packages(*2), what package the specified file belongs to(*3) and what files the specified package contains(*4).

   (*1) e.g., `$ rpm -qa`

   (*2) e.g., `$ rpm -q --requires foo`

   (*3) e.g., `$ rpm -qf /etc/foo.conf`

   (*4) e.g., `$ rpm -ql foo`

I think that Maximum RPM(http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/) is very useful site for you.